# Is it possible to set the value of the Start Property of a ServiceInstall to the value of a property?

Tags: service, wix, installation

I have a WiX installer project which needs me to allow the user to set the Start property of a ServiceInstall. Is there any way to do this? I would like to, say, pass in "auto", or "disabled" via cmd and have the service install with that startup type, or update to that startup type if an upgrade.

Right now, the only way I know to accomplish this is have separate components for each Service Startup Type and have a condition which evaluates the value of a property for each of these, which seems overly cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I had same requirement. What I did was created a custom action. On UI user will select the option and then based on selection, execute command to change the property of service.